# SQL sum from single table with join

Tags: sql

I have two table orders and orderitems.
order table has id,order_total,recieved_amount
orderitems table has id,order_id,name,total_item

I want the sum of recieved_amount, order_total from the order table and sum of total_item from orderitems. so I used

```
SELECT SUM(`received_amount`) as totalRecieved,
       SUM(`order_total`) as orderTotal
FROM   `orders` AS `Order`
LEFT JOIN `order_items` AS `OrderItems`
       ON (`OrderItems`.`order_id`=`Order`.`id`)
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(`received_amount`) as totalRecieved,
       SUM(`order_total`) as orderTotal
FROM   `orders` AS `Order`
LEFT JOIN `order_items` AS `OrderItems`
       ON (`OrderItems`.`order_id`=`Order`.`id`)
group by order.id
```

but none of them is giving me the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aggregating at two levels of your data hierarchy.  This causes a problem with Cartesian products, for each order.

The solution is to aggregate along `order_items` *before* doing the `join`:

```
SELECT SUM(received_amount) as totalRecieved, 
       SUM(order_total) as orderTotal
FROM orders o LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT oi.order_id, SUM(total_items) as total_items
      FROM order_items oi
      GROUP BY oi.order_id
     ) oi
     ON oi.order_id = o.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can benefit from cte structure or a temp table like below:

```
;with cte (order_id, SumTotalItems) as (
  SELECT oi.order_id, SUM(total_items) as SumTotalItems
  FROM order_items oi
  GROUP BY oi.order_id
)
select sum(o.receivedamount) as SumReceivedAmount
     , sum(o.order_total) as SumOrderTotal
     , cte.SumTotalItems
from orders o
left outer join cte on o.id = cte.order_id
```